# Finding a string in a string in C#

Tags: c#

I have a string, more specifically it is a piece of HTML Source code, but for some reason the lines i need is written all as one line(so basically it is all one string using ReadLine()). Now in that string i need to extract a certain word.

Here is an extracted piece of the html code. What i need is the `/Qur%27an/Luhaidan/001.mp3` part for every .mp3 file up to 114.mp3.

```
...<th scope="colgroup"><a href="/Qur%27an/Luhaidan/001.mp3"><img src="...
...<th scope="colgroup"><a href="/Qur%27an/Luhaidan/002.mp3"><img src="...
...<th scope="colgroup"><a href="/Qur%27an/Luhaidan/114.mp3"><img src="...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although in general the best approach for reading HTML is using an HTML parser, simple tasks like this one could be tackled with a regular expression.

An expression like this should work:

```
href="(.*?[.]mp3)"
```

Search for this regex in a loop, and extract the first group for the file name.

```
var str = @"
...<th scope=""colgroup""><a href=""/Qur%27an/Luhaidan/001.mp3""><img src=""...
...<th scope=""colgroup""><a href=""/Qur%27an/Luhaidan/002.mp3""><img src=""...
...<th scope=""colgroup""><a href=""/Qur%27an/Luhaidan/114.mp3""><img src=""...
";
foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(str, "href=\"(.*?[.]mp3)\"")) {
    Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[1]);
}
```

This prints

```
/Qur%27an/Luhaidan/001.mp3
/Qur%27an/Luhaidan/002.mp3
/Qur%27an/Luhaidan/114.mp3
```

[Demo on ideone.](http://ideone.com/6vWpx7)

Comment: when i try to use this richTextBox3.Text = m.Groups[1]; I get an error saying: Cannot implicitly convert type System.Text.RegularExpressions.Group' to 'string'

Comment: @FJam You can add `.Value` (i.e. make `m.Group[1].Value`) to convert a group to a `string`.

Answer (score 1):

You can get a values from one long using this method:

```
String input = @"...<th scope=""colgroup""><a href=""/Qur%27an/Luhaidan/001.mp3""><img src=""...
            ...<th scope=""colgroup""><a href=""/Qur%27an/Luhaidan/002.mp3""><img src=""...
            ...<th scope=""colgroup""><a href=""/Qur%27an/Luhaidan/114.mp3""><img src=""...";

foreach (Match match in Regex.Matches(input, @"href\=\""(.*?\.mp3)"))
{
    String yourvalue = match.Value;
}
```

In place of `yourvalue` you need to put the code that does something with the extracted value.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following code snippet to extract the mp3 file names...

```
var matches = Regex.Matches(inputMessage, @"(?<=\"")[\w\s\d/%]*?\.mp3");
```

Good Luck!